# How can I create a space delimited TXT file from XLSX using VB?

Tags: excel, vba

Alright folks, I'm still learning VB and my technical skills are pretttttty light. I have an excel file where I've set the column widths for each column I care about (not sure if that helps anything), but each field has a specific length.  There are few formatting requirements of the data (only working with numerical or text - some numerical fields have decimal place specifications). I also go over the Microsoft limit of 240 characters per line - I was given this resource for a workaround for that, but can't seem to work it in to any VB I've tried: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/prn-file-limited-to-240-characters

Note: any field that has a hard-coded value still needs to meet the spaces requirement (if hard-coded as "0", but field has 4 spaces, field must have 4 spaces). Same goes for the fields that have decimal requirements.

Field requirements are in the picture attached...I can try to put into non-pic format if needed, I couldn't figure out how to create a table in here...

[image: Field requirements]

Thanks so much in advance everyone!

Comment: The term you need for your Googling research is "fixed-width"

Comment: Unless you're really creating something which needs to fit the "prn" file format, you don't need to worry about a 240-character line limit.  That's a specific file format which does not encompass all fixed-width text files.